# Angular (TypeScript) - 'TypeError X is Not a Function' Appearing in Some Situations, But Not Others

Tags: angular, typescript, service, typeerror

I've encountered a weird situation in Angular 14 where a type error is appearing. I am able to refactor the code and work around it, but I'm curious as to why this is occurring so that I can avoid this problem in the future.

The error I am seeing is: ***ERROR TypeError: this.httpService.user_getUserInfo is not a function***

The file is called user.service.ts.

Please find an example of the code below (I've removed file imports and non-relevant code for simplicity).

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

```
export class UserService {

constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

 getUserInfo(user: string): Observable<UserInfo> {
    return this.httpService.user_getUserInfo(user);
  }

}
```

The baffling part about this is that this error does not occur in some situations.

I've played around with this for a while today and discovered that:

- If the above functionality is added to another file called users.service.ts (i.e. plural), the error disappears and everything loads correctly.
- On the flip side, if the code in users.service.ts is copied to user.service.ts, nothing works (indicating a problem with the file, not the code)
- Moving all functionality to a new file called test.service.ts did not resolve the issue.
- Renaming the file does not resolve the issue.
- Other apps we maintain have a service file called user.service.ts and no errors are generated, despite the code being similar.
- All imports of user.service.ts are correct in other files.
- Does not appear to be a caching issue with Angular, the browser or Visual Studio Code.

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Thanks.

Kevin

Comment: check the import, restart the typescript server, check if the issue happens on stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

In response to [Angular (TypeScript) - 'TypeError X is Not a Function' Appearing in Some Situations, But Not Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77962651/angular-typescript-typeerror-x-is-not-a-function-appearing-in-some-situati/77963014?noredirect=1#comment137443757_77962651) - Many thanks for your help Naren Murali. You pointed me in the right direction. I did not believe imports would be the issue as I reimported the files multiple times to ensure the relationships were correct.

However, following your comment, I started reviewing each import and doing additional tests. Whilst the imports are correct, I've discovered that this error was being caused by circular logic in the app.

user.service.ts used http.service.ts as a provider and http.service.ts was registering user.service.ts as a provider (after an orchestration call was made in http.service.ts for user information, it was being passed back to user.service.ts for another function).

Essentially, both services were relying on each other.

I'm going to refactor everything to ensure this does not occur.

Thanks again and I hope this explanation helps someone out there :)

Comment: To help other people reading your answer, be sure to include (or link to) the comment you're referring to, making this a complete answer

Comment: Hi Mika. I was unable to post the above comment in response to the original comment from Naren Murali as it was too long. I cannot see any URL reference for the comment he made. Is there a way to link to individual comments?

Comment: Yes! The date below the comment is a direct link to that specific comment. You can right-click it and pick "copy link address". It'll give you a long URL, but you can use Markdown links to make them shorter, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77962651/angular-typescript-typeerror-x-is-not-a-function-appearing-in-some-situati/77963014?noredirect=1#comment137443757_77962651)

Comment: Ahhh. Thanks. For the life of me, I could not find a link. Will keep that in mind for future :)